# How to rollback a column which has been changed

Tags: php, migration, laravel-5.1

I want to produce the below SQL query,

```
ALTER TABLE `api`.`users` CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

in `Laravel 5` another abstract layer was introduced, [change](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#changing-columns), after that you can code like this,

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `api`.`users`
        //    CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;");
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->change();
    });
}
```

What is the way to *undo* the change, how should I write my `down()`?

Unsuccessfully I tried the following.

```
public function down()
{
    //DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `api`.`users`
    //    CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;");
    $table->increments('id')->change();
}
```

**--- Edit ---**

I'm working with an existing table with live data (in fact a replica in my local environment). So I'm afraid perhaps dropping a column is not my option.

Comment: Drop the column and then re-add it?

Comment: "*I write my down()*" is there a method like this?

Comment: @giannis in a table migration file, there are two function in it: `public function up(){}` and `public function down() {}` which implies the `migrate` and `rollback` action.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the column and re-add it. Because it's auto incrementing all the existing rows should keep the same ID.

```
public function down()
{
    $table->dropColumn('id');
    $table->increments('id');
}
```

But don't forget, using increments will automatically add `unsigned` for you and all of your keys should be unsigned, including any foreign key columns.

Comment: I would avoid dropping my column with data. But then you've given me a hint where `unsigned()` is called implicitly. I'll try to play with it further.